# PythonのWebサーバでのリダイレクトができない

Tags: python

python3でhttp.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandlerを継承してWebサーバのクラスを作っているのですが、下記のように、do_POSTでデータを受け取り、処理した後、303でリダイレクトさせたいのですがブラウザの画面が変わりません。なぜなのでしょうか?

```
class handler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        # データの処理 ...
        self.send_response(303, self.responses[303][0])
        self.send_header("Location", "/")
        self.send_header("Content-Length", len(data))
        self.send_header("Content-Type", mimetypes.guess_type("views/list_view.html", False)[0])
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.send_header("Server", self.server_version)
        self.end_headers()
```

Comment: コードが全部出てないので外してるかもしれませんが、Content-Lengthをサーバが送っているので、クライアントはメッセージボディが来るのを待ってる、って可能性はありませんか。(そもそもdataには何が入っているのでしょう?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python-3.4.1とFirefox-36.0.4で、以下のコードで期待する動作を得られました。

```
import http.server

class handler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-Type", 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'<html><body>hello!<form method="POST"><input type="submit"></form></body></html>')

    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(303, self.responses[303][0])
        self.send_header("Location", "/")
        self.end_headers()


def run(server_class=http.server.HTTPServer, handler_class=handler):
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

ブラウザのデバッガ等でサーバーからの通信を見てみると原因が分かるのではないかと思います。